# How to use sed to replace u'sometext' with 'sometext'

Tags: regex, linux, sed, command-line

I have a file with text in it I simply want to strip off the leading u from all instances of `u'sometext'` so that it leaves `'sometext'`. I haven't been able to figure out how to get sed to match on `u'` and replace with `'`.

Sed command I though would work:

```
echo ['a', u'update for microsoft office 2013 (kb4022166) 32-bit edition', 'unknown', 'null'] | sed "s/u'/'/g"
```

output:

```
[a, uupdate for microsoft office 2013 (kb4022166) 32-bit edition, unknown, null]
```

what I wanted:

```
['a', 'update for microsoft office 2013 (kb4022166) 32-bit edition', 'unknown', 'null']
```

More examples of what is in the file:

```
"[u'cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_7::sp1:x64-enterprise', u'cpe:/a:adobe:acrobat:11.0.19']"
```

What I would like to have:

```
"['cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_7::sp1:x64-enterprise', 'cpe:/a:adobe:acrobat:11.0.19']"
```

Comment: please click [edit] and add the code you tried.. also, adding few sample lines (say 2-5 with made up data) along with complete expected output would help add clarity as well as help in testing solutions... the downvotes are probably because of these missing information..  see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use word boundaries, denoted with the special character `\b` which goes immediately before the first thing to be matched on a boundary

```
 $ echo "[u'a', u'hello']" | sed "s/\bu'/'/g"
 ['a', 'hello']
```

Comment: So one issue, in this case: "[ u'hello', u'hulu' ]" -> "[ 'hello', 'hul' ]"

Comment: @JediKid, I realized I mixed up where the `\b` goes. Put it in front and the hulu problem will go away

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Comment: That's not very robust, e.g. `echo "[u'version 7-u']" | sed "s/\bu'/'/g"` ->
`['version 7-']`

Answer (score 2):

Try, if possible, with something like this:

```
echo "['a', u'update for microsoft office 2013 (kb4022166) 32-bit edition', 'unknown', 'null']" | sed "s/u'/'/g"
```

OUTPUT:

```
['a', 'update for microsoft office 2013 (kb4022166) 32-bit edition', 'unknown', 'null']
```

It seems that it is not taking well the complete string but assuming it as several ones.

Comment: It was my test string that was the issue, in the file the string is wrapped in double quotes, but my echo string wasn't, this explains why it wasn't working as I expected.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo "[u'a', u'hello', u'version 7-u']" | sed "s/u\('[^']*'\)/\1/g"
['a', 'hello', 'version 7-u']

$ echo "['a', u'update for microsoft office 2013 (kb4022166) 32-bit edition', 'unknown', 'null']" | sed "s/u\('[^']*'\)/\1/g"
['a', 'update for microsoft office 2013 (kb4022166) 32-bit edition', 'unknown', 'null']

$ echo "[u'cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_7::sp1:x64-enterprise', u'cpe:/a:adobe:acrobat:11.0.19']" | sed "s/u\('[^']*'\)/\1/g"
['cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_7::sp1:x64-enterprise', 'cpe:/a:adobe:acrobat:11.0.19']
```

Note though that both the above and the currently accepted answer would fail if you can have a `u` at the end of a single-quote-delimited string earlier in the line. e.g.:

```
$ echo "['u', 'a']" | sed "s/u\('[^']*'\)/\1/g"
['', 'a']

$ echo "['u', 'a']" | sed "s/\bu'/'/g"
['', 'a']
```

so, assuming that is an issue, we can use a more robust approach with awk (in this case using GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT):

```
$ echo "['u', 'a']" | awk -v RS="'[^']*'" -v ORS= 'RT{sub(/u$/,"")} {print $0 RT}'
['u', 'a']

$ echo "[u'a', u'hello', u'version 7-u']" | awk -v RS="'[^']*'" -v ORS= 'RT{sub(/u$/,"")} {print $0 RT}'
['a', 'hello', 'version 7-u']
```